Failing to install dependencies in my flutter project
I'm facing the below error when I try to either run flutter pub get command for dependency installation or running the entire project.
flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (3.2s)
The current Dart SDK version is 3.4.3.

Because logger 0.9.4 doesn't support null safety and no versions of logger match >0.9.4 <0.10.0, logger ^0.9.4 is forbidden.
So, because farmassist depends on logger ^0.9.4, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.2.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.

I tried the following methods to resolve the issue but still it didn't help

Upgrading the logger package to the latest version
Trying removing logger dependency from the code and see if it could work


try this:
1- remove the pubspec.lock file from the root of your project
2- remove logger package from the pubspec.yaml file
3- run this flutter pub add logger command in your terminal
4- run the flutter pub get command in your terminal
let me know if it helped

Thanks for reaching out. I followed the above steps but it still showed up the same error
flutter pub add logger
The current Dart SDK version is 3.4.3.
Because farmassist depends on tflite_flutter_helper ^0.1.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.6.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.

Potential Reason
It happens because of following 2 reasons:

Any of the dependent library is outdated.

Flutter/Dart is relatively new, so is in rapid development, breaking compability with some of the existing libraries. Thus, there is no choice except to replace that library.


The constraints don't satisfy the given configuration. In this case, following solution might help you out.


Generic Solution
The generic solution to most of the configuration problem is to start fresh

Start fresh, create a brand-new flutter project with the same name, in different folder/directory.

Note:
It is recommended to be in latest version of flutter
Run flutter upgrade to upgrade to latest channel.
Run flutter channel stable to switch (if any?) to stable  channel.


Copy the lib folder from the old one, and replace it in the new project.

Install dependency manually like this,
$ flutter pub add xyz1
$ flutter pub add xyz2


This will (hopefully!) re-configure your project and will run smoothly onwards.


